# Connect JQuery .ajax function to controller function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this .ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Notification/Send',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            usr: userId,
            rcv: receiverId,
            txt: text
        },
        success: function (data) {
           //some code
        }
    });
```

and this function in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
 public string Send(string usr, string rcv, string txt)
    {


        return txt;
    }
```

so there doesn't execute 'success' block... 
what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: not error, but doesn't work... this ajax function in one JavaScript function which is invoking when press button... and after press, is not changing anything

Comment: Did you check the Newtwork and Console tabs for any error?

Comment: it works when in data method is only one argument

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint in the controller's action and running the server with debugging to make sure the action is ever hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Send(string usr, string rcv, string txt)
    {


        return Json(txt);
    }
```

If it is `GET` request then you have to do this

```
return Json(txt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your data in your ajax function like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        usr: userId,
        rcv: receiverId,
        txt: text
    }),
```

And try to specify `content type` and `dataType` explicitly:

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet.Change the return type of method

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Send(string usr, string rcv, string txt)
    {


        return Content(txt);
    }
```